# unordered_set of shared_ptr does not find equivalent objects it has stored

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a class that stores a `std::vector` of stuff. In my program, I create a `std::unordered_set` of `std::shared_ptr` to objects of this class (see code below). I defined custom functions to compute hashes and equality so that the `unordered_set` "works" with the objects instead of the pointers. This means: Two *different* pointers to *different* objects that have the *same* content should be treated as equal, let's call it "equivalent".

So far everything worked as expected but now I stumbled across a strange behaviour: I add a pointer to an object to the `unordered_set` and create a different pointer to a different object with the same content. As said I would expect that `my_set.find(different_object)` would return a valid iterator to the equivalent pointer stored in the set. But it doesn't.

---

Here is a minimal working code example.

```
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {}
    bool operator==(Foo const & rhs) const {
        return bar == rhs.bar;
    }
    std::vector<int> bar;
};

struct FooHash {
    size_t operator()(std::shared_ptr<Foo> const & foo) const {
        size_t seed = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < foo->bar.size(); ++i) {
            boost::hash_combine(seed, foo->bar[i]);
        }
        return seed;
    }
};

struct FooEq {
    bool operator()(std::shared_ptr<Foo> const & rhs, 
                    std::shared_ptr<Foo> const & lhs) const {
        return *lhs == *rhs;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<Foo>, FooHash, FooEq> fooSet;
    auto empl = fooSet.emplace(std::make_shared<Foo>());
    (*(empl.first))->bar.emplace_back(0);

    auto baz = std::make_shared<Foo>();
    baz->bar.emplace_back(0);

    auto eqFun = fooSet.key_eq();
    auto hashFun = fooSet.hash_function();

    if (**fooSet.begin() == *baz) {
        std::cout << "Objects equal" << std::endl;
    }
    if (eqFun(*fooSet.begin(), baz)) {
        std::cout << "Keys equal" << std::endl;
    }
    if (hashFun(*fooSet.begin()) == hashFun(baz)) {
        std::cout << "Hashes equal" << std::endl;
    }
    if (fooSet.find(baz) != fooSet.end()) {
        std::cout << "Baz in fooSet" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Baz not in fooSet" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Objects equal
Keys equal
Hashes equal
```

And here is the problem:

```
Baz not in fooSet
```

---

What am I missing here? Why does the set not find the equivalent object?

Possibly of interest: I played around with this and found that if my class stores a plain `int` instead of a `std::vector`, it works. If I stick to the `std::vector` but change my constructor to

```
Foo(int i) : bar{i} {}
```

and initialize my objects with

```
std::make_shared<Foo>(0);
```

it also works. If I remove the whole pointer stuff, It breaks as `std::unordered_set::find` returns constant iterators and thus modification of objects in the set cannot be done (this way). However, none of these changes is applicable in my real program, anyway.

I compile with `g++` version 7.3.0 using `-std=c++17`

Comment: What did you observe when debugging that code line by line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't modify an element of a set (and expect the set to work).  Because you have provided `FooHash` and `FooEq` which inspect the referent's value, that makes the referent *part of the value* from the point of view of the set!

If we change the initialisation of `fooSet` to set up the element *before* inserting it, we get the result you want/expect:

```
std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<Foo>, FooHash, FooEq> fooSet;
auto e = std::make_shared<Foo>();
e->bar.emplace_back(0);  // modification is _before_
fooSet.insert(e);        // insertion
```

Looking up the object in the set depends on the hash value not changing.  If we really need to modify a member after it has been added, we need to remove it, make the changes, then add the modified object - see [Yakk's answer](/a/52821587).

To avoid running into issues like this, it may be safer to use `std::shared_ptr<const Foo>` as elements, which will prevent modification of the pointed-at `Foo` through the set (although you're still responsible for the use of any non-const pointers you may also have).

Comment: Thanks, that solved it! To be honest, I don't really see why exactly my approach did not work. I did not modify the elements of the set as they are just the pointers, right? The pointers don't change, just the stuff that they point to... could you maybe clarify what exactly is going on there?

Comment: By your definition of equals (in `FooEq` and `FooHash`), you *did* change the value - those functions make the pointed-to object become part of the value, from the set's point of view.

Comment: Omg of course, that's why I implemented the custom hash stuff in the first place m( Now I see it, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Any operation such that the hash or `==` result of an element in an `unordered_set` violates the rules of `unordered_set` is bad; the result is undefined behavior.

You changed the result of a hash of an element in an `unordered_set`, because your elements are shared pointers, but their hash and `==` is based off of the value pointed to.  And your code changes the value pointed to.

Make all `std::shared_ptr<Foo>` in your code `std::shared_ptr<Foo const>`.

This includes the equals and hash code and unordered set code.

```
auto empl = fooSet.emplace(std::make_shared<Foo>());
(*(empl.first))->bar.emplace_back(0);
```

this code is right out, and it will (afterwards) fail to compile, as is safe.

If you want to mutate an element in a `fooSet`,

```
template<class C, class It, class F>
void mutate(C& c, It it, F&& f) {
  auto e = *it->first;
  f(e); // do this before erasing, more exception-safe
  auto new_elem = std::make_shared<decltype(e)>(std::move(e));
  c.erase(it);
  c.insert( new_elem ); // could throw, but hard to avoid.
}
```

now the code reads:

```
auto empl = fooSet.emplace(std::make_shared<Foo>());
mutate(fooSet, empl.first, [&](auto&& elem) {
  elem.emplace_back(0);
});
```

`mutate` copies an element out, removes the pointer from the set, calls the function on it, then reinserts it back into the `fooSet`.

Of course in this case it is dumb; we just put it in and now we take it out mutate it and put it back.

But in a more general case it will be less dumb.

Comment: @TobySpeight `;` and `is bad` added, word deleted.

Comment: Great advice to change to `std::shared_ptr<Foo const>`, this will save me from (at least some) trouble in the future, thanks!

Comment: If we are unable or unwilling to copy elements (obviously not an issue for shared pointers, but could be a consideration for a set of containers), we might want to use `extract()` to obtain and operate on a node handle - but we'd have to decide whether to re-insert it if `f()` throws.

Answer (score 0):

Here you add an object and it's stored using its current hash value.

```
auto empl = fooSet.emplace(std::make_shared<Foo>());
```

Here you change the hash value:

```
(*(empl.first))->bar.emplace_back(0);
```

The set now has an object stored using the old/wrong hash value. If you need to change anything in an object that affects its hash value, you need to extract the object, change it and re-insert it. If **all** mutable members of the class are used to calculate the hash value, make it a set of `<const Foo>` instead.

To make future declarations of sets of `shared_ptr<const Foo>` easier, you may also extend the std namespace with your specializations.

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {}
    size_t hash() const {
        size_t seed = 0;
        for (auto& b : bar) {
            boost::hash_combine(seed, b);
        }
        return seed;
    }
    bool operator==(Foo const & rhs) const {
        return bar == rhs.bar;
    }
    std::vector<int> bar;
};

namespace std {
    template<>
    struct hash<Foo> {
        size_t operator()(const Foo& foo) const {
            return foo.hash();
        }
    };
    template<>
    struct hash<std::shared_ptr<const Foo>> {
        size_t operator()(const std::shared_ptr<const Foo>& foo) const {
            /* A version using std::hash<Foo>:
            std::hash<Foo> hasher;
            return hasher(*foo);
            */
            return foo->hash();
        }
    };
    template<>
    struct equal_to<std::shared_ptr<const Foo>> {
        bool operator()(std::shared_ptr<const Foo> const & rhs,
                        std::shared_ptr<const Foo> const & lhs) const {
            return *lhs == *rhs;
        }
    };
}
```

With that in place, you can simply declare your unordered_set like this:

```
std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<const Foo>> fooSet;
```

which now is the same as declaring it like this:

```
std::unordered_set<
    std::shared_ptr<const Foo>,
    std::hash<std::shared_ptr<const Foo>>,
    std::equal_to<std::shared_ptr<const Foo>>
> fooSet;
```